# Does a TCP peer reset the connection after exhaust the send retry counter?

Tags: windows, tcp, network-protocols

Supose a Windows TCP peer sending a TCP packet and the remote peer not ACK'ing it neither reseting the connection (kernel crash, power/hardware failure,etc.)

Does the windows peer reset the connection after exhaust the send retry counter?

Does the TCP RFC say something about it?

My doubt arises after reading the following sentence (in "Re-transmission Behavior" paragraph of this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169292/en-us):

> After computer "X's" retries are exhausted, you may not see a "Reset"
>   right away. If computer "Y" finally responds, computer "X" may then
>   reset the connection.

Thanks in advance and forgive me for my rudimentary english.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of an ACK for the entire send window, the sender assumes that that the peer has gone away and silently cleans up the connection (no FINs or RSTs sent at this stage) after retries.

If the peer was actually alive and sends a packet on the old connection, the sender will then send a RST.

Comment: Thank you very much jman. I have another question! What happens if I try to use the same socket from another thread of the same process (after no ACK received). Thank you!

Comment: If the old-connection still exists on the server, but the client tries to establish a new connection with the same 4-tuple, the SYN is rejected and the server responds with an ACK for the expected sequence number. Client will then send a RST. See fig 10 in the RFC: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html.

Comment: If you try to reuse the socket that failed to get ACKs, you will get ECONNRESET from your own side.